# How to show errors of server validations in bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with server validations in bootstrap modal. I want open a modal with my form and to do submit, but if exists some error in my model i want show messages of errors. I don't know how to do this.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult NovoComportamento(Guid id)
        {
            ViewBag.Icon = "icon-plus";
            ViewBag.Title = "Novo Comportamento de Componente";

            var comportamentoComponente = new ComportamentoComponenteViewModel();

            comportamentoComponente.ComponenteFormId = id;

            return PartialView("~/Views/ComportamentoComponente/_ComportamentoComponente.cshtml", comportamentoComponente);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NovoComportamento(ComportamentoComponenteViewModel comportamentoComponenteViewModel)
        {
            var errorList = new List<ValidationError>();

            ViewBag.Icon = "icon-plus";
            ViewBag.Title = "Novo Comportamento de Componente";

            var componenteSalvoNoBanco = _componenteFormAppService.ObterPorId(comportamentoComponenteViewModel.ComponenteFormId);

            if (componenteSalvoNoBanco == null)
            {
                errorList.Add(new ValidationError("Não é permitido adicionar um comportamento a componente que não está salvo na base de dados."));
                return Json(new ActionResponse(false, errorList, comportamentoComponenteViewModel));
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var comportamentoReturn = _comportamentoComponenteAppService.Salvar(comportamentoComponenteViewModel, comportamentoComponenteViewModel.ComportamentoComponenteId);

                if (!comportamentoReturn.ValidationResult.IsValid)
                {
                    foreach (var error in comportamentoReturn.ValidationResult.Erros)
                    {
                        errorList.Add(new ValidationError(error.Message));
                    }

                    return Json(new ActionResponse(false, errorList, comportamentoComponenteViewModel), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

                return Json(new ActionResponse(true, null, comportamentoComponenteViewModel), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(new ActionResponse(true, errorList, comportamentoComponenteViewModel), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My PartialView with modal form:

```
@model PAD.Application.ViewModels.ComportamentoComponenteViewModel

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null,
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                        },
                        new { id = "comportamentoComponenteFrm", onsubmit = "comportamentoSubmit()" }))
        {
            <div class="card-header modaldialog">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <span class="@ViewBag.Icon"></span> @ViewBag.Title
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ul id="listaErros"></ul>
                    </div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ComponenteFormId)
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo)
                            <select class="form-control" name="tipo" id="combotipo">
                                <option value="">-- Selecionar --</option>
                                <option value="A">A - Acessibilidade</option>
                                <option value="P">P - Aparência</option>
                                <option value="V">V - Visibilidade</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Condicao)
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Condicao, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "10" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="classe-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Classe)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Classe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning shadow" type="button" id="voltar-lista-comportamentos">
                    <span class="icon-reply"></span> Voltar
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-success shadow pull-right" type="submit">
                    <span class="icon-check"></span> Salvar
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script src="~/Content/js/comportamento-componente.js"></script>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#classe-group").hide();

    $("#combotipo").change(function () {
        var tipo = $("#combotipo").val();

        if (tipo == "P") {
            $("#classe-group").show('slow');
        } else {
            $("#classe-group").hide('slow');
        }
    });

    var componenteFormId = $("#componente-id").val();

    $("#btnNovoComportamento").click(function () {
        var url = "/ComportamentoComponente/NovoComportamento/";
        $("#modal").load(url + componenteFormId, function () {
            $("#modal").modal("show");
        });
    });

    $("#voltar-lista-comportamentos").click(function () {
        var url = "/ComportamentoComponente/ListaComportamentosComponente/";

        if (componenteFormId == "" || componenteFormId == undefined || componenteFormId == null) {
            swal("Erro", "Nenhum componente foi selecionado!", "error");
        } else {
            $("#modal").load(url + componenteFormId, function () {
                $("#modal").modal("show");
            });
        }
    });

    function comportamentoSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/comportamentocomponente/novocomportamento',
            data: $("#comportamentoFrm").serialize(),
        }).done(function (result) {
            swal("OK!", "A requisição foi feita.", "success");
            if (result.data != null && !result.data.success) {
                swal("OPS!", "Existem alguns erros.", "error");
                var errors = result.data.errorList;
                $.each(errors, function (key, value) {
                    $("#listaErros").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
                });
            } else {
                swal("OK!", "Comportamento de Componente cadastrado com sucesso!", "success");
                $("#modal").modal("hide");
                $("#comportamentoFrm").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I Know should use Json, but don't know how to get the result with javascript and show the errors in partial view modal without close the modal. I want to close modal only when not exists errors.

This is return submit:

[image]

Comment: What kind of error you are taking about ? Validation errors or any error or exceptions happens in the server side ?Are you getting any data in result.data.errorList ? Did you check with debugger ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Domain errors, ModelState errors ... I want to get to the Controller, make all the necessary validations on my domain layer and on the modelstate, if there is something I disagree with, I would like to return those errors for my partial modal view. That is, I would like to keep the modal open as long as it is necessary to display validation errors coming from my controller.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. After the submit in the form, Action on the Controller is triggered and when it returns, it is simply a JSON string without any formatting.

Comment: can we see the  string ?

Comment: Firstaball why your Post action `NovoComportamento` doesn't return a View instead of json ? You could add Validation error in the `ModelState` and would allow you to display a modal containing a `ValidationSummary()` on page load.

Comment: But will this allow me to display validation errors still in bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 0):

i use someting like that

in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult yourMethode(model myModel)
    {
     var errorModel = from x in ModelState.Keys where ModelState[x].Errors.Count > 0 select new { key = x, errors = ModelState[x].Errors[0].ErrorMessage };
                return Json(new { Error = true, Data = errorModel, responseText = "Erreur Model" });
    }
```

in jquery ajax error

```
 error: function (request, error) {
 if (JSON.parse(request.responseText).Data[0] != null) {console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText).Data[0].errors)}
}
```